# Weird icon on MUI TextField with Safari Browser

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, safari

i use MUI Component Library with my React Project and I got this weird icon on my textfield when i use my app on Safari browser. Any idea what's it?
[image: image on safari]

I expect it's seems normal like on other browser
[image: image on another browser]